# Let the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R_k [x]$ of the polynomials...

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R_k [x]$ of the polynomials of minor degree or equal to $k$, with coefficients in $\mathbb R$, and are $B_1$ = {$1, x, x^2, ... , x^k$} $B_2$ = {$L_0(x),L_1(x), … ,L_k(x)$}, where
> $L_i(x) = \prod_{{j=0}_{j\neq i}}\frac{(x – j)}{(i – j)}$, $0 \le i \le k$.

> a) Calculate $L_1(j)$ for $0 \le i$ , $ j \le k$.

> b) Show that $B_2$ is a basis of $R_k[x]$.

> c) If $g(x) \in R_k[x]$, find $[g(x)]_{B_2}$ .

> d) Find $[Id]^{B_2}_{B_1}$ .

I'm completely lost, I definitely don't understand $B_2$.

$\mathbb R_k [x]$ is of the form $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_kx^k$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}_k[x]$ is not itself of the form $a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_k x^k$ but rather the *set of* all polynomials of this form. (The description “polynomials of minor degree or equal to $k$” does not make much grammatical sense in English, though. There’s probably a non-native speaker involved somewhere.)

Each $L_i(x)$ as defined in the first paragraph is such a polynomial, i.e. an element of $\mathbb{R}_k[x]$. Therefore, $B_2$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}_k[x]$. You are tasked with showing that this subset is a basis.